# 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'mapReduce' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I'm using pyMongo 1.11 and MongoDB 1.8.2. I'm trying to do a fairly complex Map/Reduce. I prototyped the functions in Mongo and got it working, but when I tried transferring it to Python, I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Developer/R-and-D/<ipython-input-71-3c3a43221538> in <module>()
----> 1 results = db.user_actions.mapReduce(map, reduce, "user_entities_interactions")

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1099                         "call the '%s' method on a 'Collection' object it is "
   1100                         "failing because no such method exists." %
-> 1101                         self.__name.split(".")[-1])

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'mapReduce' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

My collection looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "entity_id" : 1556, "user_id" : 466112 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "entity_id" : 1366, "user_id" : 10057 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "entity_id" : 234, "user_id" : 43650 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "entity_id" : 6, "user_id" : 34430 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "entity_id" : 461, "user_id" : 3416 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "entity_id" : 994, "user_id" : 10057 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "entity_id" : 296, "user_id" : 466112 }
```

The code I'm running in Python is:

```
map = Code("""function () {
        emit(this.user_id, { 
            user_id : this.user_id,
            entity_id : this.entity_id});
    }""")

reduce = Code("""function (key, values) {
        var entities = { user_id : values[0].user_id, entity_id : [ ] };
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            entities.entity_id[i] = values[i].entity_id;
        }
        return entities;
    }""")
results = db.user_actions.mapReduce(map, reduce, "user_entities_interactions")
```

What the result *should* look like is:

```
{ "_id" : 3416, "value" : { "user_id" : 3416, "entity_id" : 461 } }
{ "_id" : 10057, "value" : { "user_id" : 10057, "entity_id" : [ 1366, 994 ] } }
{ "_id" : 34430, "value" : { "user_id" : 34430, "entity_id" : 6 } }
{ "_id" : 43650, "value" : { "user_id" : 43650, "entity_id" : 234 } }
{ "_id" : 466112, "value" : { "user_id" : 466112, "entity_id" : [ 1556, 296 ] } }
```

I'm not clear on what the problem is. The error says that the 'Collection' object has no mapReduce method, but that's clearly not true as the example at http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/map_reduce.html works and what is 'things' if  not a collection?

Also, in case you're wondering why I'm not doing this with group() it's because I have **more than 20000 unique keys**.

Answer (score 7):

It's not called `mapReduce`, but [`map_reduce`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.3/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.map_reduce). Try:

```
results = db.user_actions.map_reduce(map, reduce, "user_entities_interactions")
```

Comment: Ack! Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem**

As mentioned in all the answers, the problem is that the MapReduce method in `pymongo` is actually written with underscores, i.e. [map_reduce](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.3/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.map_reduce), to fit into the most used Python code style.

**The Confusing Error**

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'mapReduce' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

The error might seem very much confusing and take you in the wrong direction. The point here is, that MongoDB uses internal/system collection names that use a *dot*, e.g. `system.namespaces`, `system.indexes`, `system.profile`, etc. Although MongoDB does not let you use a *dot*-ed name to create a new collection, anyway you may query existing system collections. So while you run your `user_actions.mapReduce` code, it actually treats `user_actions.mapReduce` as a single collection, i.e. instance of Collection object, and then tries to execute the `__call__` method on that object, which does not exist. Thus the error.

The good part it is that `pymongo` considers this case, and hints about the possibility that you were trying to execute the `mapReduce` method on the corresponding Collection object which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

read that linked page again, the method is called `map_reduce`

also, in that example `things` *is* a collection, it's get created when you insert the first document in it.

Answer (score 0):

One update on this, PyMongo 4.0 Removed pymongo.collection.Collection.map_reduce(). Using 4.0+ version of pymongo will give same error for map_reduce method.

Details can be found [here](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate-to-pymongo4.html#collection-map-reduce-and-collection-inline-map-reduce-are-removed)